# Letters with Accents are shown on my local server but not on my prod server

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8

On my Local Server emulate by **MAMP**, it returns all the letters with accent correctly.
On my Production Server Host by **Dreamhost**, it returns a question mark within a diamond for this accent: â..

When I make an ajax request on my Production Server, I can't encode my object in JSON because it doesn't recognize my string values as an UTF-8 encoding (have to use utf8_encode).

What should I do to resolve this problem ? I Can not find any answer.

**EDIT**

I'm using a **Database** using **utf8_unicode_ci** for itself, all the tables and raws with string type.

Request Header from Prod

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, *
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImFlNW5ZbmljWkcwcVM5XC9QdGxtZGZZVUxwK2tZNWZiYlwvYkdPSHdIcGxkcz0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjE0RU51M1ZYVlwvM1U2QlR0MjFuOGo2WXVtUXFLQkJzWFVRbjBoV2thVmZzSWNaOXozQVJXQjRHZFNjMkp6b0Z0RjZoV1wvN2Y0bVwvdThpbkpwdFdcL0U4Zz09IiwibWFjIjoiODE1YzJhZDYwMWU4MDkwMjM1YTg2NjU1MGVkMmZiNGZiOWVlNWJhODc3ZTAyOGVlOGEzMjJhMDRlYzdjNmIxMiJ9; _ga=GA1.2.474837750.1412291587; _gat=1; Hm_lvt_aff7c47cb709e5851f8459e1408034c6=1412291588; Hm_lpvt_aff7c47cb709e5851f8459e1408034c6=1412432225
Host:www.mywebsite.com
Referer:http://www.mywebsite.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Response Header from Prod

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sat, 04 Oct 2014 14:17:05 GMT
Expires:Sat, 04 Oct 2014 14:17:06 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=2, max=99
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

Request Header from Local

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, *
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Im1lSnNnTFRjbnFqU29NVVdoT1V2M0lqSlY1SncxdTF0MVwvd2QrNzFLT21jPSIsInZhbHVlIjoidzdxb2k2Zld3aUhJaWRKZnhIeFJ1XC9zeG1uaTNGblRETEkwd04ra1FjK0F5Y0JxQk1CbW9jdDNpcU01NE1BQlgxSmN6MXFDRkVBbjhRRFBqRXdpcFVRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI2MmE2YTIzNDBiNjE5NjM2ZGE5NjNhOGQxZWU5YjIyMTZmNjI3NWVlNjdhYzY1ZDY1OGE5OTE3NTgyM2I5YzM2In0%3D
Host:localhost
Referer:http://localhost/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Response Header from Local

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sat, 04 Oct 2014 14:16:49 GMT
Expires:Sat, 04 Oct 2014 14:16:50 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/5.5.14 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please show us the **complete** HTTP response of **BOTH** AJAX requests, from production and development servers? Are there any differences in content or length?

Comment: You should provide could you use. We also don't know if you use database or not. If yes, for example you imported data in wrong way or it could be even server configuration issue. If you simple use put `â` into your template (for example Blade) is this letter also displayed wrong ?

Comment: Yes For Example With The August month in french it becomes Août.
And my prod server returns "ao�t" whereas my local server return août.
For this case I'm not talking about AJAX Request.

Comment: @KeizerBridge So try first with normal text (not from database) and look if it is being displayed fine

Comment: Yes It displays fine when directly type "août" in my blade template.
But the "août" I'm talking about comes from the returned value of the strftime() php function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `setLocale('fr_FR')` now I have `setLocale('fr_FR.UTF8')` and it solves the problem!

Laravel doesn't throw any error anymore using json_encode() for any AJAX request.
my strftime function return the right characters fo each letter with an accent.